# How to solve No operation available for request in SUDS?

Tags: python, salesforce, suds

first I imported SUDS client and logging

```
from suds.client import Client as SudsClient
import logger

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

I was provided with two wsdl files, an enterprise.wsdl and ProgrammerClientHandler.wsdl.xml.
i used enterprise.wsdl to login by:

```
# Authentication and get more information for set up
enterprise_client = SudsClient(enterprise_url)
response = enterprise_client.service.login(username, "%s%s" % (password,token))
```

then i'll get the sessionId and serverUrl to transfer to another SUDS client object

```
session_id = response.sessionId
server_url = response.serverUrl

soap_header = enterprise_client.factory.create('SessionHeader')
soap_header.sessionId = session_id
```

then i direct the SUDS client to the user by the server_url that was given

```
programmerclienthandler_client = SudsClient(handler_url)
programmerclienthandler_client.set_options(soapheaders=[soap_header])
programmerclienthandler_client.set_options(location=server_url)
programmerclienthandler_client.set_options(port = 'ProgrammerClientHandler')
```

if I print programmerclienthandler_client it shows this

```
Service ( ProgrammerClientHandlerService ) tns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/axlea/ProgrammerClientHandler"
Prefixes (1)
  ns0 = "http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/axlea/ProgrammerClientHandler"
Ports (1):
  (ProgrammerClientHandler)
     Methods (1):
        getProgrammerClientXML()
     Types (5):
        ID
        LogCategory
        LogCategoryLevel
        LogInfo
        LogType
```

now i need to call the getProgrammerClientXML() function by:

```
 programmerclienthandler_xml = programmerclienthandler_client.service.getProgrammerClientXML()
```

now when I call this I get the error:

```
DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode><faultstring>No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/axlea/ProgrammerClientHandler}getProgrammerClientXML</faultstring></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
Error: ERROR: Server raised fault: 'No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/axlea/ProgrammerClientHandler}getProgrammerClientXML'
```

What should I do to make it work? Is there a problem in the wsdl files?

Comment: P.S. I'm new in SUDS and salesforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serverUrl returned by login is for the enterprise API, but you're not using that, you shouldn't change the endpoint URL of your `programmerclienthandler_client` stub, its already correct.

Comment: So i should remove this:
programmerclienthandler_client.set_options(location=server_url)

and how do I use the serverUrl returned by login?

Comment: when I removed it, it returned a different error.
    'Error: ERROR: Server raised fault: 'No service available for class 'axlea.ProgrammerClientHandler'''

Comment: sounds like you might not have access to the class in the sfdc setup.

Comment: and if its a managed package, your user account will need to be assigned a license for it.

Comment: so the problem is on the account?

Comment: Yeah, It seems like your request is going to the right place, but the user account you're using is not setup correctly.

Comment: ah i see. ok thanks Sir Fell. I'll get back to you once the account is finished.

Comment: Hello sir, can you tell me something about this error. Error: ERROR: Server raised fault: 'UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService'

Comment: You're sending the request to the login service, see my original answer about removing the call that changes the location property